# Suggestions on asynchronous image loading for UITableView in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, asynchronous, afnetworking

I am currently loading my table with a left-sided thumbnail, title and subtitle using this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *post           = [posts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text       = [post objectForKey:@"post_text"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [post objectForKey:@"post_author_name"];

    NSString *postpictureUrl = [post objectForKey:@"picture"];
    NSData   *data           = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postpictureUrl]];

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    return cell;
}
```

Of course this will not work in production due to the synchronous loading I am doing here.

What is your suggestion for asynchronous loading of images in a situation like this?

I've found [AF Networking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) (haven't used it yet) but wonder if there's a more lightweight approach to this issue.

Comment: This might help. It's pretty in depth and goes into loading remote images using threading. http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial

Comment: lazy loading is the best approach for this case.. [Apple Sample code for LazyLoading](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394)

Comment: @Bala I saw that one but thought it was full of pre-ARC code (although it says it's iOS 5+)

Comment: i think,it is very simple to make it using ARC ,. Just give a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AsyncImageView` is your friend, check it out [here](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView).

Just set the `imageURL` and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
Use lazy loading in table view
Use this code


    (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {

            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        NSDictionary *post = [posts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.text = [post objectForKey:@"post_text"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [post objectForKey:@"post_author_name"];
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,  0ul);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
         //This is what you will load lazily
      NSString *postpictureUrl = [post objectForKey:@"picture"];
        NSData   *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postpictureUrl]];
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                [cell setNeedsLayout];
      }); 
}); 

        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: if you are still getting problem with lazy loading.Please let me know.

Comment: @user1573162 - the code does not seem to compile as there are closures missing - also I've tried another version of this and the images don't show - any changes you'd like to make to your suggestion above? thx!

Comment: thx @user1573162 , no errors but it doesn't show the images to the left (title and subtitle) load OK -- BTW the line with `[cell setNeedsLayout];` needs to be removed

Comment: @user1573162 - OK now I notice that when I tal on the table cell the image appears on the left - why would that be the case? is there a need for a placeholder?