# Update views while being touched

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, tableview

I am having an app where I load images in a `UITableView`. Each row has an image view.

1. I download images from URL and assign it to `UIImageView`. The problem here is that the image views are not updating if I was dragging the table view. It only updates when I release the finger.
2. Another problem is that I have a label in all cells that shows a counter which is incremented using a timer. Timer action is also not getting called when my finger is on the table view.

How do I do the updates in both these cases?

May be this is a very basic question. But I have no clue.

Thanks everyone!

***EDIT:*** I have noticed that ***-connection:didReceiveResponse:*** method is not getting called when the view is being touched.

***EDIT 2:*** I tried adding run loop with NSURLConnection. My method looks like this.

```
- (void)start {

    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:self.imageURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:self.timeoutInterval];
    [request setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];  
    _connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

    NSPort* port = [NSPort port];
    NSRunLoop* rl = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]; // Get the runloop
    [rl addPort:port forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    [_connection scheduleInRunLoop:rl forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    [_connection start];
    [rl run];
}
```

This loads the images even when I am touching on the view. But the table view is scrolling very slowly. Its not even scrolling. It only moves when I drag. No movement after I release the finger.

Comment: How are you downloading images? I guess the problem is that these works on thread which get blocked while you drag

Comment: for your 1st problem i prefer you to use extended `UIImageView` class i have developed, you can download [here](https://github.com/DipenPanchasara/LazyImageView) i am sure it will solve 1st issue, regarding 2nd one i guess, you need to call update section method to refresh your tableView, no other options.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara, why should he call `ReloadSections` if he want just change of one(or more) label? This method not for that. Just change label.text should be enough.

Comment: try updating content on scroll delegate..

Comment: same way he can update single cell by the tim

Comment: @EmptyStack, provide some source code, please. There could be too many reasons for such behavior.

Comment: use dispatch_queue and update/reload particular indexpath while you downloaded image.

Comment: Are you assigning `NSRunLoop` to your `NSURLConnection` and `NSTimer`? If yes, put the runloop in `NSRunLoopCommonModes` instead of `NSDefaultRunLoopMode`.

Comment: @Amar, Thanks. I got the timer to be working with NSRunLoop. But NSURLConnection is not still working. Any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: @EmptyStack For downloading images in tableview cell you can make you of [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). It is very easy to use!

Comment: @EmptyStack Can you also post code where you create and start `NSURLConnection`? If you are performing this on a background thread, possibility is the thread is exiting before the delegate methods are called.

Comment: @Amar, I am already using EGOImageLoading (https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading/tree/master/EGOImageView). Do you think SDWebImage is better than EGOImageView. Please let me know your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: @EmptyStack I have not used EGOImageLoading yet so can't comment on that. SDWebImage has worked for me till now :) In your case you can try this work around. In `EGOImageLoader.m` method `loadImageForURL:style:styler:completion:` Replace `if(anImage){completion(anImage, aURL, nil);}` with `if(anImage) {dispatch_async(kCompletionsQueue, ^{completion(anImage, aURL, nil);}}`. Check if this works.

Comment: @Amar, I'll try this. But, I think the problem is in *EGOImageLoadConnection.m*. The ***-connection:didReceiveResponse:*** is not getting called if the view is being touched. Is there any workaround for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem 1**

The solution is to use downloading mechanism that doesn't get blocked while you drag the table view. **[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)** is an asynchronous image downloader with cache support with an UIImageView category. This will let your image view to be updated even if you are dragging your table. I have faced a the same issue in my project where i used SDWebImage. Just a call like this will do.

```
 [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

**Problem 2**

If its scheduledTimer will not get called while the main thread is tracking touches. Do something like this. Just create a timer and add to loop

```
NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateLabel:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

this will not interrupt your timer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have got the timer working with NSRunLoop. How do I make NSURLConnection work. I have noticed that *-connection:didReceiveResponse:* method is not getting called when the view is being touched. Thanks.

Comment: use the SDWebImage. Normal NSURLConnection will be blocked till the table stops dragging. Or you have to use another thread using NSOperationQueue. check these http://stavash.wordpress.com/2012/12/14/advanced-issues-asynchronous-uitableviewcell-content-loading-done-right/ , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654192/suggestions-on-asynchronous-image-loading-for-uitableview-in-ios

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my answer. Could you please check that. Thanks.

Comment: try using NSDefaultRunLoopMode

Answer (score 0):

this might be some helpful to you because you downloading images for displaying in `UItableViewCells`  here i am giving you the example of the  anything in background without `blocking UI` there you can get good tutorial link.they have mentioned enough good way same thing.[go through this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632994/populating-images-in-uiscrollview-and-how-to-do-it-lazily/16633345#16633345)

And Rest of the thing could be solved with the help of as `Meera j Pai` mentioned in his Answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with both ***NSConnection*** & ***NSTimer*** using the answers given by *@Amar* & *@Meera J Pai*, by using ***NSRunLoop***.

I have changed my connection code to be like this.

```
_connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO]
[_connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];    
[_connection start];
```

It worked great!

Thanks everyone.